# Routed Event descriptor field 'ClickEvent' missing, Xaml, UWP

Tags: storyboard, eventtrigger, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to create an animation on a button using the following code in Xaml on a Windows 10 UWP app:

```
<Button x:Name="EoIdButton" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,0,0,0" view:EventHandlers.Attach="Click" BorderBrush="DarkGray" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="{Binding EoIdButtonContent, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource SegoeConverter}}" Style="{StaticResource CircleButtonStyle}" Visibility="{Binding EoVis, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Button.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="EoIdButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="0,0,40,0"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Button.Triggers>
            </Button>
```

I get the error indicated as mentioned in the title and the `.Click` portion of the EventTrigger line, is underlined blue and shows the error.  When I try to run it, it breaks.  I've tried adding a normal Click event to the button and it doesn't change anything.  I have my own click handler that I attach to my view model, so I thought maybe it just needed a normal code behind handler, and I guess I was wrong.  I must be missing something else?